# cost of switching to MAXDOP=1 in prod

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql-server, performance

Have a client who's Sql Server instance serving SP2010 databases has `MAXDOP=0`. What are **immediate**/postponed cost in terms of resource usage (CPU/mem/IO) when `MAXDOP` is set to 1?

**Should then I apply it ASAP or wait for minimum farm usage hours?**

**UPDATE** This is **NOT** a dublicate Q: I've marked the important part

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 this option is must have thing, without it you cannot configure the SharePoint. That's mean it is important piece of configuration, we had set since the launch of SharePoint 2010 and had no issue.

> this has been tested pretty comprehensively and gives best performance
>   and without this setting it is possible to see Table Scans for some
>   content databases under various conditions. Yes, many of the Stored
>   Procedures now have this set as a hint in many (>150 stored procs) but
>   as a general rule for a SharePoint specific SQL environment, set this
>   value to 1.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/lukeb/archive/2011/09/08/sharepoint-maxdop-1.aspx

that's mean if your setting is not 1 then if Optimerzer see no index on table or  dont want to use existing index then it perform table scan. which is resource extensive process and delay you query execution time and user has to wait for longer time.

to understand the Table-scan concept, please see this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224773(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Thx, alot of info I didn't asked for and already read about) I need to know will the switch itself costs anything?

Comment: no it will not, rather it will increase the performance. I would advice to change it after hours.